# atoi() — string to int

Tags: c

I read that `atoi()` is deprecated and that it is equivalent to:

```
(int)strtol(token_start, (char **)NULL, 10);
```

Does that mean I should use the above instead of `atoi(chr)` or is it just saying they are equivalent?

Comment: My problem with `atoi`: `assert( atoi("0") != atoi(!blah") )`

Comment: `atoi` is poor because it does almost no well-defined error detection, but even when using `strtol`, properly detecting (and classifying) errors is surprisingly difficult, and none of the answers here really addresses that.  See the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074422/why-cant-you-just-check-if-errno-is-equal-to-erange/) for some guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does say on Apple's [Mac OS X Manual Page for atoi(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atoi.3.html) (and in the BSD man pages too) that `atoi` has been deprecated.

> The atoi() function has been deprecated by strtol() and should not be
>   used in new code.

I would use the `strtol()` equivalent just for that reason, but i doubt you have to worry about `atoi()` being removed.

<strike>from http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php
Implementation Notes</strike>

```
* The atoi function is not thread-safe and also not async-cancel safe.
* The atoi function has been deprecated by strtol and should not be used in new code.
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend only on the internal implementation of the `atoi` whether it's thread-safe or not? If not, then what makes it not thread-safe on the outside?

Comment: They must've tried really hard to make it not thread safe. The naive implementation sure is.

Comment: It is important to note that not every compiler supports sto* functions yet, like Android NDK. See this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499070/stdstring-operations-i-e-stol-stoi-not-found-ndk8d

Comment: glibc man page for atoi says: "The atoi(), atol(), and atoll() functions are thread-safe with exceptions.  These functions can be safely used in multithreaded applications, as long as setlocale(3) is not called to change the locale during their execution."

Comment: This answer, or rather the source, is incorrect/irrelevant. Whether or not a certain function is thread-safe indeed depends on the compiler implementation. I don't see why it wouldn't be. atoi is no different from strol functions in this regard. More so, atoi is most certainly not deprecated. It wasn't in 2009 and it isn't now either, in the C11 standard.

Comment: @Lundin i cannot delete this answer because it is the accepted one, so i updated it.  I found that the BSD and OSX man pages do say it's deprecated, although i don't know what the original question is referring to.

Answer (score 22):

`atoi` is not deprecated, your source is incorrect. Nothing in the current C standard ISO 9899:2011 indicates this (see for example chapter 6.11 future language directions), nor anything in earlier standards.

As per the C standard, atoi is equivalent to strtol as follows, C11 7.22.1.2:

> The atoi, atol, and atoll functions convert the initial portion of the
>   string pointed to by nptr to int, long int, and long long int
>   representation, respectively.
>
> Except for the behavior on error, they are equivalent to
>
> `atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`
>
> `atol: strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`
>
> `atoll: strtoll(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`

strtol is preferred, as atoi invokes undefined behavior upon error. See 7.22.1 "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined."

Comment: (Yes I know this question is terribly old but the accepted answer is incorrect, had to be clarified)

Comment: "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined".  Surely this make the function completely unusable, and is sufficient reason to consider the function effectively deprecated.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Indeed. Give the C standard committee a couple of decades more and they might realize. For example, it took them 22 years to remove `gets`. The very epitome of efficiency and initiative. Compare this with the MISRA-C safe subset standard, which banned all use of the ato* functions as early as 1998.

Answer (score 4):

The [description of `atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) has one very important point in relation to the similarities/differences to `strtol()`

`> ... The call atoi(str) shall be equivalent to:`
`> (int) strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10)`
**`> except that the handling of errors may differ.`**

<s>Try this for fun:</s>

```
const char *buf = "forty two";
int t1 = atoi(buf);             /* detect errors? */
int t2 = strtol(buf, NULL, 10); /* detect errors? */
```

Comment: I've tried your code on my compiler (GCC) and both gave me `0`, so I don't see any difference :|

Comment: Hmmm, my bad! Thanks @SasQ. I thought `strtol` had to set `errno` on error, but in the specific case of my test code above, it doesn't.

Comment: @pmg Your test code doesn't seem to check `errno` at all.

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't use the above instead of `atoi`.

You should actually check the error information that `strtol` makes available:

```
i = atoi(s);
```

should be replaced by

```
char* stopped;
i = (int)strtol(s, &stopped, 10);
if (*stopped) { /* handle error */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

- `atoi()` is not deprecated by the prior or the current C standard.
- `atoi(nptr)` is like `(int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10);` **except on errors**.

---

Now, **how to detect and resolve errors?**

Consider using a helper function: `int atoi_alt(const char *nptr, int *errorptr);`

Possible errors and candidate resolutions:

- Out-of-range: conversion leads to a value outside the [`INT_MIN` ... `INT_MAX`] range like `atoi_alt("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890", ...);`.  Return either `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX` (matching the sign of the original conversion) and a non-zero error.
- No conversion: conversion fails as the string begins with non-numeric, non-white-space text like `atoi_alt("!@#$1234", ...);`.  Return 0 and a non-zero error.
- No conversion: conversion fails as the string is empty like `atoi_alt("", ...);`.  Return 0 and a non-zero error.
- Non-numeric trailing text: Initial conversion works, yet extra, non-white-space, text exists like `atoi_alt("1234!@#$", ...);`.  Return converted value and a non-zero error.  Note that with `strtol()`, this is not an *error*.
- White-space trailing text: Initial conversion works, white-space follows like `atoi_alt("1234\n", ...);`.  Return converted value and a zero error.  Note that with `strtol()`, this is not an *error*.
- White-space begins text: Ignore leading white-space and convert as above. Note that this is consistent with `atoi()` and `strtol()` and itself is not an *error*.
- String not supplied: As `nptr == NULL`, return 0 and a non-zero error.  Note that with `strtol()`, this is *undefined behavior* (UB).
- Error address not supplied: Perform as above, but do not set an error.

Sample alternative code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// To Do: refine error codes, perhaps as enum?
#define ATOI_BAD_ARG 1
#define ATOI_NO_CONVERSION 2
#define ATOI_RANGE 3
#define ATOI_EXTRA 4
int atoi_alt(const char *nptr, int *errorptr);

// Side effect: errno is assigned.
int atoi_alt(const char *nptr, int *errorptr) {
  int dummy;
  if (errorptr == NULL) {
    errorptr = &dummy;
  }
  if (nptr == NULL) {
    *errorptr = ATOI_BAD_ARG;
    return 0;
  }

  errno = 0;
  char *end;
  long lvalue = strtol(nptr, &end, 10);
  if (nptr == end) {
    *errorptr = ATOI_NO_CONVERSION;
    return 0;
  }

#if LONG_MIN == INT_MIN && LONG_MAX == INT_MAX
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    *errorptr = ATOI_RANGE;
    return (int) lvalue;
  }
#else
  if (errno == ERANGE || lvalue < INT_MIN || lvalue > INT_MAX) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    *errorptr = ATOI_RANGE;
    return (lvalue < 0) ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
  }
#endif

  while (isspace(((unsigned char* ) end)[0])) {
    end++;
  }

  *errorptr = *end ? ATOI_EXTRA : 0;
  return (int) lvalue;
}
```

Code purposely does not carry the error information back to the caller via `errno` - my design choice.  Easy enough to amend code to do otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

it means that at one point in time atoi will not be available anymore. So start changing your code now

Comment: I get that part, but was wondering if atoi's implementation just called the code above.

Comment: This is incorrect, citation needed. Nothing in the current C standard indicates that atoi is deprecated. And this is 6 years after this answer was made, with C11 being the active standard.