# std::string operations (i.e. stol, stoi) not found NDK8d

Tags: android, android-ndk

I try to set up my first android project using ndk r8d with c++11 support.
Some c+11 mechanisms work fine (i.e. lambada expressions), but when i try
to use one of the new string operations, the compile fails ( error: 'stol' is not a member of 'std'). Here are my
project settings:

Application.mk

```
APP_MODULES := MyLib   

APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x  
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG   

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM:=android-14                      

APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_GNUSTL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7
```

Are those functions actually not working?

Comment: have you tried searching in different namespaces like tr1, tr2 or ext?

Comment: If I try to use the namespaces std::tr1, std::tr2 and std::ext, I got the failure message that those are not declared.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be answered in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124627/731722).

> The reason why you cannot use the functions is quite deep rooted, and unfortunately currently unsolvable.

In GNU STL implementation of these function somehow relies on c99 (_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 macro), that is not used by Android

> The root cause seems to be that the C99 functionality usage has been disabled in the GNU stdlibc++ on the armeabi-v7a platform due to the fact the the Bionic libc does not support complex math (the standard C library on Android is Bionic).

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

APP_STL := c++_static

to Application.mk fixed this issue for me (using gcc 4.8.4).

solution via Daniel Tavares, from this [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/pQ2Qv8GPcwA).

Comment: c++_static is still experimental : https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#cs