# How to use std::stoul and std::stoull in Android?

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk

C++11 has two new string conversion functions into `unsigned long` and `long long`: `std::stoul()` and `std::stoll()`.

The recent Android NDK r9 introduces Clang 3.3 compiler which is said to be C++11 feature complete. There are prototypes for these functions deep inside NDK, however I cannot use them.

What do I need to do to use them?

**P.S.** I already do `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11`

Comment: Probably similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616254/enable-c11-support-on-android. but instead use clangs c++11 library. (I think its `-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11` for the LOCAL_CFLAGS)

Comment: I already do ``-std=c++11``

Comment: `-stdlib=libc++` is also needed make sure you try it

Comment: Added -stdlib=libc++ and defined __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ Still no success.

Comment: I have no idea. I can't get this to work. I think some define is missing but I can't tell which. If you do a `-E` to show the preprocessor output you can see that `bits/basic_string.h` is included and that appears to be where `stoll` is defined however `stoll` does not appear in the preprocessor output.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The reason why you cannot use the functions is quite deep rooted, and unfortunately currently unsolvable.

Looking into the `libs/armeabi-v7a/include/bits/c++config.h` file in the gnu stdlibc++ folder, you'll see this:

```
...
/* Define if C99 functions or macros from <wchar.h>, <math.h>, <complex.h>,
   <stdio.h>, and <stdlib.h> can be used or exposed. */
/* #undef _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 */
...
```

The above, in conjunction with the following snippet from `bits/basic_string.h` spells bad news:

```
...
#if (defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
     && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))

/* The definitions of Numeric Conversions [string.conversions] */
#endif
...
```

Thus, these functions are unusable in the NDK.

**Root Cause:** The root cause seems to be that the C99 functionality usage has been disabled in the GNU stdlibc++ on the armeabi-v7a platform due to the fact the the Bionic libc does not support complex math (the standard C library on Android is Bionic).

**Possible Fix (untested):** Explore [CrystaX's Android NDK](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk.php) which seems to have extensions over the Vanilla Android NDK.

**Note:** `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` is defined by adding `-std=gnu++11` to `APP_CXXFLAGS` or `LOCAL_CXXFLAGS`

**Detailed Test log:** Built using NDK version r8e
*jni/Application.mk*:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.7
```

*jni/Android.mk*

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := cxx11
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cxx11.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

*jni/cxx11.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
#if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
    std::cout<<"__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ defined."<<std::endl;
#else
    std::cout<<"__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ not defined."<<std::endl;
#endif

#if defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99)
    std::cout<<"_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 defined."<<std::endl;
#else
    std::cout<<"_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 not defined."<<std::endl;
#endif

#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF)
    std::cout<<"_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF defined."<<std::endl;
#else
    std::cout<<"_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF not defined."<<std::endl;
#endif

#if (defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
     && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))
    std::string s="1";
    std::cout<<"ll:"<<std::stoll(s)<<std::endl<<"ul:"<<std::stoul(s)<<std::endl;
#else
    std::cout<<"No support for stoll/stoul."<<std::endl;
#endif
    return(0);
}
```

Output on Nexus 4 (Android 4.3):

```
u0_a51@mako:/ $ /data/local/tmp/cxx11
__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ defined.
_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 not defined.
_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF not defined.
No support for stoll/stoul.
```

Comment: Any chance to replace stdlib?

Comment: @SergeyK. Try [CrystaX's Android NDK](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk.php), which seems to have some fixes over the Vanilla Android NDK. I am looking to explore it as well.

Comment: Have you tried NDK r9? Maybe we can define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 manually?

Comment: @SergeyK. Naah. Already tried `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D _GLIBCXX_USE_C99=1`. It's a very deep-rooted problem.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a great answer.

Comment: @Leco As I mentioned "Possible fix" section in the answer and in the comment to SergeyK, take a look at  [CrystaX's Android NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk.php), which is a rebuild of the standard NDK with full C++11 support

Comment: Thanks. I only needed std:stol so I copied the implementation from source and used it in my project.

Comment: For anyone landing here years later, the current fix is to switch to libc++ (`APP_STL := c++_shared` if you're using ndk-build). It doesn't have these problems.

Comment: @DanAlbert please post a solution instead of this comment. Better for all that way.

Comment: @DanAlbert the question is about `std::stoul` while the answer by Mark S. is about `std::stoi`.

Comment: It's the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Adding:

APP_STL := c++_static

to Application.mk fixed my issue of not being able to access std::stoi() (using gcc 4.8.4).

solution via Daniel Tavares, from this [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/pQ2Qv8GPcwA).

Comment: Did this also fix the issue of access to the `unsigned long` and `long long` variants of the functions(`stoul` and `stoll`)?

Comment: That solution helped me with stoul(). Thanks.