# std::stoul errors out on a Qt app for android with NDK r13b

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, android-ndk, qmake

I `Qt app` which works on `android`. I am writing code which is pretty much `C++ 14` standard. Using functions like `make_unique` & `make_shared` as well.

However when I try to use `std::stoul`, **it only fails to compile on `android`**. It compiles & works for `clang` on `osx` & `iOS`. Works for `Microsoft compiler on windows`. But only fails to compile on Android with the following error saying :-

```
error: 'stoul' is not a member of 'std'
```

My `Qt app` uses latest `NDK r13b` to compile the code for `android`.

I searched around quite a bit & found similar problems people are facing like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950814/how-to-use-stdstoul-and-stdstoull-in-android) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support). **But, I need a way to resolve this on a `Qt app`. for `android`**

I added the following to my `Qt App`'s `.pro` file. But doesnt work.

**How can I make `std::stoul` compile in a `Qt app` for `android` using latest `NDK r13b` ?**

Also tried adding the following block to my app's `.pro` file. **But doesn't help**.

```
android {
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -std=c++1y
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -std=c++1y
 CONFIG += c++14

 QMAKE_APP_FLAG +=c++_static
}
```

Comment: As long as you are using Qt I would suggest you to use QString as much as you can. You can for example do QString(YOUR_STRING).toLong(). Here YOUR_STRING may as well be a standard C++ string.

Comment: I am writing this code in core C++ class. this code has to be strictly C++. I don't have that `QString` option

Comment: Ok, what compiler are you using in Android? As a last resource you can try the old good sscanf function like sscanf(str.c_str(), "%ld, &yourInteger) if stoll is not available.

Comment: the compiler is gcc with the version that latest ndk provides

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to work around this is to inject the functions into namespace std. Please note that you may need to implement these in a more correct manner, as I've only just scabbed in some code to make this look correct. So make a new file called whatever you like and add this:

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H

#if defined(__ANDROID__)
namespace std {
    unsigned long stoul(const std::string &str)
    {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        auto returnValue = atoi(str.c_str());
        if (returnValue == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("stoul: invalid string " + str);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
#endif

#endif //MYFILE_H
```