# using c++11 with ndk

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, dlib

i am trying to use some dnn features from dlib in https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android but i am always getting errors like

```
error: no member named 'to_string' in
      namespace 'std'
```

and many more syntax errors

my application.mk file is like this

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_STL := gnustl_static
#APP_CFLAGS+=-DDLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT=on
#APP_CFLAGS+=-DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT=off
APP_CFLAGS+=-DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT=on
APP_CFLAGS+=-DDLIB_JPEG_STATIC=on
```

According to me c++11 should be working ..I dont get where's the problem

Comment: You might have to use a different STL implementation. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18124627/1524450

Comment: well that did solved the particular problem surprisingly but now opencv compilation is giving error of std functions being absent.No idea why take a look at this->                              std::range_error::range_error(std::string const&)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82

The fix for this is to switch from gnustl to libc++, but note that libc++ isn't as stable as gnustl is yet (working on fixing this ASAP, should be ready by the time r15 hits stable).

EDIT: As of NDK r16 libc++ is the recommended STL. Switch to using libc++ (see [our docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#selecting_a_c_runtime)) for full C++11 (and beyond) support.

Comment: Well..I am r14 and it's showing invalid value for stl

Comment: Ok so waiting  for r15

Comment: @ArpitKhurana Any solution now?

Comment: The solution is to use libc++.