# Why can't you just check if errno is equal to ERANGE?

Tags: c, errno, strtol

I've been trying to properly convert a char array to a long with `strtol`, check if there was an overflow or underflow and then do an int cast on the long. Along the way, I've noticed a lot of code that looks like this

```
if ((result == LONG_MAX || result == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE)
{
   // Handle the error
}
```

Why can you not just say

```
if(errno == ERANGE)
{
    // Handle the error
}
```

From my understanding, if an underflow or overflow occur, errno is set to ERANGE in both cases. So is the former really necessary? Could checking ERANGE alone be problematic?

This how my code looks as of now

```
 char *endPtr;
 errno = 0;
 long result = strtol(str, &endPtr, 10);

 if(errno == ERANGE)
 {
     // Handle Error
 }
 else if(result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN)
 {
    // Handle Error
 }
 else if(endPtr == str || *endPtr != '\0')
 {
     // Handle Error
 }

 num = (int)result;
 return num;
```

If there is a reason for the former please let me know.

Comment: I've never seen a good explanation for why it is necessary to check for both `LONG_MAX/LONG_MIN` and `ERANGE`. Apart from the fact that the man page shows that as an example. The only sensible use case I can think of is to differentiate between overflow and underflow. I too would be interested to hear whether there are other reasons.

Comment: @kaylum I don't know I feel that my example is right mostly because I don't intend to differentiate whether an overflow or underflow occurred and that errno is set to ERANGE in both cases. If either one of them occurred, than the result is invalid.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Maybe I wasn't clear. But I was agreeing with you that your version of error checking looks fine to me.

Comment: @kaylum Opps, sorry about that man.

Comment: @kaylum There is one valid check that I forgot to do and I think man page even talks about and that is if `errno != 0 && result == 0`. Though to be honest, I'm not sure what could cause that because if strtol returns a 0, then I'm positive strtol does not set errno to anything assuming it was initially set to zero.

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet is more correct than the 2 answers.  IMO it is correct and optimal other than I would just do `if(errno)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first code snippet is just plain wrong, and I'll explain why later, but first we need some background.

`errno` is a [thread-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe) variable. It is set to a non-zero value when a system call or certain library functions fail. It remains unchanged when a system call succeeds. So it always contains the error number from last call that failed.

This means that you have two choices. Either set `errno` to 0 before each call, or use the standard idiom for `errno`. Here's the pseudo-code for the standard idiom

```
if ( foo() == some_value_that_indicates_that_an_error_occurred )
    then the value in errno applies to foo
else
    foo succeeded and the errno must be ignored because it could be anything
```

Most programmers will use the standard idiom, because setting `errno` to 0 before every system call is annoying and repetitive. Not to mention the fact that you might forget to set `errno` to 0 in the one place it actually matters.

---

Back to the first code snippet. It is wrong because there is no return value from `strtol` that unambiguously indicates that `strtol` failed. If `strtol` returns `LONG_MAX`, it could be that an error occurred, or the string actually contained the number `LONG_MAX`. There's no way to know whether the `strtol` call succeeded or failed. Which means that the standard idiom (which is what the first code snippet is trying to implement) cannot be used with `strtol`.

To use `strtol` correctly, you need to set `errno` to 0 before the call, like this

```
errno = 0;
result = strtol( buffer, &endptr, 10 );
if ( errno == ERANGE )
{
    // handle the error
    // ERANGE is the only error mentioned in the C specification
}
else if ( endptr == buffer )
{
    // handle the error
    // the conversion failed, i.e. the input string was empty,
    // or only contained whitespace, or the first non-whitespace 
    // character was not valid
}
```

Note that some implementations define other non-zero values for `errno`. See the applicable man page for details.

Comment: Good answer, but one point: strictly speaking, `strtol` is a library function, not a system call.  And it's unusual in that it does manipulate `errno`.  Most (all?) system calls set `errno` when they fail, but few library functions do.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. If you don't might me asking but is it possible for `errno != 0 && result == 0`? I have seen code where they incorporate that and `if((result == LONG_MAX || result == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE)` Like if you set errno to zero right before you call strol to convert A123. You expect result to be 0 and errno to stay at zero. What could cause errno to not be zero in that situation?

Comment: @SteveSummit That's true, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the answer without introducing needless complexity. I hope it's ok to leave it as a comment.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff  `strtol` will return `0` if no conversion could be performed. In that case the value in `errno` is implementation defined. The C spec doesn't specify what value should be stored in `errno` in that case. So yes, you could have a return value of 0, and a non-zero `errno`.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a nitpicker, but I was surprised to read "It is set to a non-zero value when a system call fails", as if `strtol` was a system call.  You could change that to "It is set to a non-zero value when a system call or certain library functions fail", and also change "set `errno` to 0 before each system call" to "set `errno` to 0 before each call".

Comment: @user3386109 So if it is implementation defined than there is no point in checking for that or if errno = ERANGE if you are checking if there was an overflow or underflow.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Yup, I had to rethink that part. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Disagree with "To use strtol correctly" as it does not check the case of "no conversion"  Need to add `if (buffer == endptr) Handle_NoConverisonError();`

Comment: @SteveSummit: Most library functions are not specified by the C standard to set `errno`, but many of them do so anyway (or are required by POSIX to do so). `fopen` is an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you call

```
result = strtol("-2147483648", NULL, 0);
```

or

```
result = strtol("2147483647", NULL, 0);
```

on a 32-bit machine, you're going to get `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` in `result`, even though there hasn't been an error.

As user3386109 explained, one way to detect errors from `strtol` is to set `errno` to 0 first.  The other way is to let it give you an end pointer and look at that.  There are three or four cases:

```
char *endptr;
long int result = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
if(*str == '\0') {
    /* str was empty */
} else if(endptr == str) {
    /* str was completely invalid */
} else if(*endptr != '\0') {
    /* numeric result followed by trailing nonnumeric character(s) */
} else {
    /* str was a completely valid number (perhaps with leading whitespace) */
}
```

Depending on your needs, the first two or three cases may be collapsed together.  You may then need to worry (a) whether the "completely valid number" was representable (which you can test using `errno`), and (b) whether any "trailing nonnumeric character(s)" were innocuous whitespace (which, alas, `strtol` doesn't check for you, so if you care you'll have to check yourself).

Comment: so there is no point in saying `if(result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN) because result is always going to equal to either INT_MAX or INT_MIN if there is an overflow or underflow in regards to an int correct? I should just check if result is equal to either one of them.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Sorry, I said `INT_MAX` when I meant `LONG_MAX`. (Fixed now.)  But in general I'd say there's never any reason to explicitly test the return value of `strtol` against any min or max value.  (The only reason might be to compare against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` if you were about to store the value into a plain int.)

Comment: Yes I was about to store the value into a plain int.

Comment: @SteveSummit My turn to nitpick ;) Trailing whitespace won't be consumed, so `*endptr` could point to a space character or newline. Specifically, the word "trailing" in the last comment isn't true.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks. I coulda sworn I read about a version that stripped trailing whitespace, and it's been in my head that way ever since, but you're right, the documentation doesn't mention it.  Fixed.

Comment: `if(*str == '\0')` as a special case is not truly needed as an empty string will get caught  in `if(endptr == str)`