# Checking just integers and no strings using fgets only

Tags: c, fgets, stdio, atoi

I'm trying to get an integer number from command line without `scanf()` but using just`fgets()`, how can I filter the `fgets() contents`reporting an error if I insert a character or a string? The problem is that when I insert something different like a character or a string the `atoi()`function (essential to do some operations in my algorithm) converts me that string to 0, whilst I'd prefer to exit if the value inserted is different from an integer.
Here's a code part:

```
.....
char pos[30];
printf("\n Insert a number: ");
fgets (pos, sizeof(pos), stdin);
if (atoi(pos) < 0) //missing check for string character
    exit(1);
else{
printf ("%d\n", atoi(pos)); //a string or character converted through atoi() gives 0
}
int number = atoi(pos);
......
```

Comment: using something like [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) is preferred because of the error checking.

Comment: Don't use `atoi`. Use `sscanf` and check the return value, or use `strtol` and [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074422).

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved on my own using `strcspn()`before checking through `isdigit()`the integer type, without strcspn() it'd have returned always -1

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have said, use `strtol()` not `atoi()`.

The problem with `strtol()` is that it will only give an `ERANGE` error (as per the specification) when the converted number will not fit in a long-type.  So if you ask it to convert `"   1"` it gives `1`.  If you ask it to convert `"apple"`, it returns `0` and sets `endptr` to indicate an error.

Obviously *you* need to decide if `"    12"` is going to be acceptable input or not — `strtol()` will happily skip the leading white space.

**EDIT**: Function updated to better handle errors via the `endptr`.

```
// Convert the given <text> string to a decimal long, in <value>
// Allow a string of digits, or white space then digits
// returns 1 for OK, or 0 otherwise
int parseLong( const char *text, long *value )
{
    int rc = 0;    // fail
    char *endptr;  // used to determine failure

    if ( text && value )
    {
        errno = 0;                               // Clear any errors
        *value = strtol( text, &endptr, 10 );    // Do the conversion

        // Check that conversion was performed, and
        // that the value fits in a long
        if ( endptr != text && errno != ERANGE ) 
        {
            rc = 1;  // success
        }
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: It is an error if you type `Apple` and don’t allow hex. And `strtol()` tells you if you pay attention, but the report is subtle. In particular, you can’t use NULL for the second argument as that’s what is used to report conversion failure.

Comment: Note [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176593/15168).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanks for the heads-up on `endptr`, I edited the answer.

Comment: Do you want to discuss checking whether what follows is permissible?  For example, trailing white space might be fine, but any other character (e.g. a letter or punctuation such as a dot) might be inadmissible.  Now you've got `endptr`, you can tell where the conversion ended and check whether the characters after what was converted were allowable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to keep in mind that characters are not essentially alpha characters; be precise.

I think what you're looking for is an "is integer" function.
In the standard C library `ctype.h` there are functions called `isalpha` and `isdigit`.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isalpha

So you could make a function that verifies if a `char *` contains only numeric characters.

```
int str_is_only_numeric(const char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (isdigit(str[i++]) == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a working example of the function: https://onlinegdb.com/SJBdLdy78

Comment: This ignores the possibility of `+, -` and leading/trailing white-space.

Comment: But it doesn't work if I insert a number into my buffer, it returns -1 anyway:
int check_int (char s[], int n){

    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0'){
        if (isdigit (s[i++]) == 0)
     return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}