# Add 2 decimals in c while using strtol() and fprintf()

Tags: c, addition

I am new to programming and I got the homework to write a program that adds 2 numbers.
I have to use strtol() to convert strings to int. Also in case the user does not input anything or just 1 number I have to use fprintf to display an error. The same for the case that the user inputs characters, or if the user inputs more than 2 numbers.
My current attempt looks like this: (the // is the part that does not work for me)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
        long number1;
        long number2;
        char *end;

        number1 = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
        number2 = strtol(argv[2], &end, 10);

//      if(isdigit(number1)==0) fprintf(stderr, "Given argument '%s' is no valid integer!\n",        argv[1]);
//      else if(isdigit(number2)==0) fprintf(stderr, "Given argument '%s' is no valid integer!\n", argv[2]);
//      if(argc <=2){   fprintf(stderr, "Required summand is missing!\n");      return 1;}
//      if(argc >=4){   fprintf(stderr, "Superfluous argument was given! Only two are allowed.\n");     return 1;}

        printf("%ld\n", number1+number2);

        return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

For the fprintf I was trying to determine somehow how much the user has put in (1 or 2 or 3 things)
and whether the input is a digit with isdigit(), or if it is too much or too less input with the 3rd and 4th if statement.

Comment: `isdigit` is used to check whether a single character in a string is a digit. Using it on a number returned by `strtol` makes no sense.

Comment: Aside, you should be checking `argc` *before* you access `argv`.

Comment: [This question discusses how to perform error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074422/) when using `strtol`.