# How do I get a negative value by using atoi()?

Tags: c, atoi

I wrote this code to get a number in reverse form. But if I use any negative input it shows positive reversed number. Can the atoi function in C handle negatives?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char ar[40];
  char ar2[40];
  int fnum;
  scanf("%s", ar);

  for (int i = strlen(ar) - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
    ar2[j] = ar[i];
    j++;
  }

  fnum = atoi(ar2);
  printf("%d", fnum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but where do you terminate `ar2`? Remember that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*.

Comment: As for your question, in a string containing a negative number, where is the minus character? After reversing, where will the minus character be?

Comment: Your loop is backwards. If you enter in a positive number, it will also be printed in reverse. Is this intentional? Negative numbers will show as positive because the `-` occurs at the end of the string and is not treated as part of the number.

Comment: because if you enter "-12345" you convert it to "54321-".  You need to check if the 1st character is a dash.

Comment: You have to copy minus sign from last to first position. Otheriwse `atoi` cannot return negative value.

Comment: [don't use `atoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: How can you read your own code, the formatting and indentation is truly awful. Please learn about this, it's important or no one will ever enjoy reading your code.

Comment: The _null character_ is not set in `ar2[]`, so `atoi(ar2);` is UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strstr(haystack, needle)` to convert it to negative number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
char ar[40];
char ar2[40];
int fnum;
scanf("%s",ar);
for(int i=strlen(ar)-1,j=0;i>=0;i--){
    ar2[j]=ar[i];
    j++;
}
if(strstr(ar, "-"))
    fnum= - atoi(ar2);
else
    fnum= atoi(ar2);
printf("%d",fnum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strstr(ar, "-")` is undefined behavior (UB) as `ar2[]` is not certain to have a _null character_ terminating it.

Answer (score 3):

Before last `printf` put this line:

```
if ( atoi( ar ) < 0 ) fnum = -fnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `atoi(ar2);`.  Use `strtol(ar2, NULL, 10);`

From linux `man atoi`,

> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as
>
> strtol(nptr, NULL, 10);
>
> except that atoi() does not detect errors.

It seems an error in the man page.  `strtoul()` is a better choice for `atoi()` replicant, but `strtol()` is a good solution to this question.

See also: [atoi() string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488569/atoi-string-to-int)