# usage difference between "atoi" and "strtol" in c

Tags: c

I have been using `atoi` for a year now and I have an issue in the recent days that the expression:

`atoi("20")` is giving a value of `0` as output.

When I Google'd the issue I found that it is deprecated and `strtol` should be used instead.

The interesting point I came to know is `atoi` internally uses `strtol`. So, how can the issue be solved when I change it to `strtol`?

Comment: `atoi` sill works.. `atoi("20")` should return `20`. The problem is in  _your_ code which you didn't show. [Edit] your question and show a [mcve]. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: If you find that `atoi("20")` return 0, you should change your development tool or your computer... `atoi` has been deprecated by `strtol` because the latter handles the first character following the digits, which may matter.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. The `atoi()` function might be deprecated, but it does still work just fine: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/_Ngaca)

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know that I have to post the code. But the thing the project is big and if it helps I am using freertos for multitasking.

Comment: `atoi` has undefined behavior, `strtol` doesn't. See [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think what you have told makes sense. But in the first iteration it works and in the second iteration it doesn't!

Comment: @phuclv _"atoi has undefined behavior"_: what makes you think that? Do you have any reference?

Comment: @SaitejaPabisetti you're not supposed to post your entire code, just the relevant section (or more precisely, a section of code that demonstrates the problem). Just check out my link, which clearly shows that atoi() still works as expected

Comment: @phuclv the thing I didn't understand is atoi uses strtol behind the scenes.

Comment: @SaitejaPabisetti the fact that `atoi` uses `strtol` or not is irrelevant. `atoi` does what the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) says, no more and no less. The bug is in _your code_. Maybe `atoi` is too limited for your usage, we don't know without seeing some source code.

Comment: @phuclv that's not exactly what you have written in your first document.

Comment: @Jabberwocky that's exactly what I said: atoi can invoke UB

Comment: `atoi` has been used for decades. If *at a moment in your program* `atoi("20")` returns `0`, it is just an evidence that *anywhere in the program* you have Undefined Behaviour. C is a low level language, and consequences of UB are not necessary local. That is even the reason why it is called *Undefined Behaviour*...

Comment: I reckon the problem will be solved in an instant once you provide the relevant code. I really doubt that your program has `atoi("20")` with a literal string in it. It's more likely to be `stoi(str)`, where you think that `str` should be `"20"`, but don't check. Your comment that "in the first iteration it works and in the second iteration it doesn't" makes it clear: The problem is in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The explication from `man` page:

The  `atoi()` function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as:

`strtol(nptr, NULL, 10);`

except that atoi() does not detect errors.
The atol() and atoll() functions behave the same as atoi(), except that they  convert the initial portion of the string to their return type of long or long long.

For more infos, you can see the difference of two functions in this topic [atoi - strtol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488569/atoi-string-to-int)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the data, `strtol()` has greater functionality

```
int easy = atoi(data);
// no errors detected
```

---

```
char *err;
errno = 0;
long tmp = strtol(data, &err, 10);
if (errno) /* deal with errno: overflow? */;
if (tmp > INT_MAX) /* int overflow */;
if (tmp < INT_MIN) /* int "underflow" */;
if (*err) /* extra data */;
int comprehensive = tmp; // convert from long
```

Comment: I think that you'll have to #include errno.h and limits.h to take advantage of this greater functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946552/584518) by pmg that explains how `strto...` has more functionality and error checking, the `ato...` functions are guaranteed by the standard to behave like this (C17 7.22.1.2):

> Except for the behavior on error, they are equivalent to
>
> ```
> atoi:  (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
> atol:  strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
> atoll: strtoll(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
> ```

That being said, `ato...` are not required to *call* `strto...` internally (though this is the case in many libs), just to behave identically save for the error handling.

Please note that the `ato...` functions are not formally listed as obsolete yet. But they should be avoided still, mainly because it is pointless to use `atoi` when we can as well use `strtol(str, NULL, 10)`, the latter being identical but with better error handling.