# How do i add up all elements of a command line argument

Tags: c

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int a;
    for(int i=1;i<=argc;i++){
        a+=atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    printf ("%d",a);
}
```

I keep getting segmentation faults but i am trying to add up all elements of the command line so for example ./a.out 5 6 7 would give 18 as the output, cheers.

Comment: arrays are 0 based (first element in index 0). you need: `for(int i=0;i<argc;++i)`

Comment: @wohlstad that seems like a solution to the problem, shouldn't that be an answer then?

Comment: @wohlstad Not really, `argv[0]` is the program name in one form or another, so it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the correction. You are right of course. I just focused on the issue of accessing array elements in general.

Comment: On an unrelated note: You don't initialize the variable `a`. It will have an *indeterminate* (consider it garbage) value.

Comment: On yet another (unrelated) note: The `atoi` function doesn't really have any kind of validation of the strings you pass to it. There's no way to differ between invalid input and the input `"0"` for example. If you want proper validation use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem (with the crash) is the loop itself:

```
for(int i=1;i<=argc;i++)
```

The `argc` argument is the number of arguments passed to the program, including the "program name" at `argv[0]`. So valid indexes for the actual arguments are `argv[1]` to `argv[argc - 1]`.

Furthermore the `argv` array is terminated by a null pointer, which will be at `argv[argc]`.

Since you include `argv[argc]` in your loop you pass a null pointer to `atoi` which leads to *undefined behavior* and likely crashes.

The simple solution is to use less-than `<` instead of less-than-or-equal as the loop condition:

```
for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
```

Comment: See my comment on the other answer. :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole I did, and which is why I rephrased my answer to focus on the crash itself. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized `a` to `0`. Also, use [`strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946754/17939455) function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        a += strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: _You need to check whether the passed argument is a valid number_ - why? 0 can be a perfect value for "not a number"