# C - How to read integer at certain place in the argument vector?

Tags: arrays, c, text, io, argv

I'm writing a C program that reads table data from a *.txt* file, applies changes to it and prints the modified table to a different *.txt* file. Part of the program is the function that prints and empty line before the line entered in the terminal after the *irow* argument. Here's how the program is compiled and run:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o main main.c
./main irow [row]  <tab1.txt >tab2.txt
```

Part of the program that handles the input:

```
int insertRow(char*argv[], int row_number) {
    row_number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; argv[i]; i++) {
        if ( isdigit(argv[i][0]) && (strcmp(argv[i - 1], "irow") == 0))
            if((argv[i][0] - '0') > 0)
                row_number = argv[i][0] - '0';
    }
    return row_number;
}
```

Then the *row_number* is used in the main method to perform the changes on the table.

The code works and performs what it's supposed to, however I haven't yet come up with a better way of reading the *[row]* parameter from the argument vector. How can I read not only the first digit but the whole integer inside the string of that argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first executable statement of your function is to set `row_number` to 0, there is *no* need to have it as an argument. It ignores the passed in value and *returns* the final value.

Also, there are simpler ways to use `argv` than to index into it.

And, if you had arguments of:

```
23 irow 17
```

Your function won't handle that well. It would try to decode `23` instead of `17`

It is simpler to have a "state" variable and look at only one argument at a time.

And, you can/should use `atoi` to get all the digits [vs. decoding only the first digit of the number string].

Here's a refactored version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
insertRow(char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    int match = 0;
    int row_number = 0;

    for (cp = *argv++;  cp != NULL;  cp = *argv++) {
        // we just saw "irow", so this is the number
        if (match) {
            row_number = atoi(cp);
            break;
        }

        // if current token is "irow", next token is the number
        match = (strcmp(cp,"irow") == 0);
    }

    return row_number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To turn a string containing a number into an `int`:

```
row_number = atoi(argv[i]);
```

Also, you're not supposed to get `row_number` in the signature. You're not using its value, and any changes you make to `row_number` won't affect the calling function.
You should instead define it inside the function:

```
int row_number = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice to define inside the function and the atoi solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488569/atoi-string-to-int

Comment: You should avoid atoi.  On certain inputs, it will invoke undefined behavior.