# error: cast to 'string' (aka 'char *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: arrays, c, computer-science, cs50

I was solving caesar problem from CS50, and I got this error.
What does this error means?

I was expecting to print the key (which is type casted from string to int)
Help me to get the answer.......

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool isnotdigit(string inp_key);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

   int key;
   if (argc > 2 || isnotdigit(argv[1]))
   {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
   }
   else{
    key = (int) argv[1];
    printf("%i\n", key);
   }
}
bool isnotdigit(string inp_key)
{
  
 int uac = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k != strlen(inp_key); k++)
    {
        if (isalpha(inp_key[k]) || isblank(inp_key[k]) || isspace(inp_key[k]))
        {
            uac++;
        }
        else
        {
            uac += 0;
        }
    }

   if (uac > 0)
   {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: `(int) argv[1]` (casting from string to int) doesn't do what you think it does. You may want to use `strtol` or `sscanf` instead.

Comment: Can I use "atoi"?

Comment: You may find this helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488569/atoi-string-to-int

Comment: Also, it looks like you are trying to define `isnotdigit` inside of `main`. Functions cannot be defined inside other functions.

Comment: In a pinch, but bear in mind that it should not be used in real code. `strtol` will do its job *and* the job of `isnotdigit`, for free.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this line:

```
key = (int) argv[1];
```

Try instead:

```
key = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Edit 1: As a side note, your `isnotdigit` function is a bit buggy in the for loop `k != strlen(inp_key)`, and you could achieve the same result in your function without the `uac` variable by exiting the for loop if detected a char that is not a number.